# PHP Unzipping a file in Google App Engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, unzip

I'm using Google app engine 1.9 and I want to unzip a uploaded .zip file using PHP. Since the ZipArchive is not available in App Engine I tried using PclZip (http://www.phpconcept.net/pclzip/) as described in this post

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9856

However, once I tried it, I get the following error.

Here, I'm giving the **public url** of the .zip file. And the url is something like **https://my-storage.storage.googleapis.com/folder/my_file.zip** (This is not the real url).

```
"PCLZIP_ERR_MISSING_FILE (-4) : Missing archive file 'https://my-storage.storage.googleapis.com/folder/my_file.zip'"
```

I also tried changing the url as **gs://my-storage/folder/my_file.zip'** format and it gives me the following error.

```
 "PCLZIP_ERR_BAD_FORMAT (-10) : Unable to go to the end of the archive 'gs://my-storage/folder/my_file.zip'"
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: This is likely related to this known issue: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10881

Comment: is there a workaround?